# Xdebug not writing to file

Tags: php, xdebug

I am trying to learn xdebug. I have the following script:

```
<?php

echo "This";

xdebug_start_trace('/home/dotancohen/xdebug');
echo "That";
xdebug_stop_trace();

?>
```

My `/home/dotancohen/` directory is permissions 711 and the `~/xdebug` file is permissions 777. However, the file is not being written to. There  are no errors thrown in the PHP script, and it functions exactly as one would expect disregarding the xdebug lines.

Why might the file not be written to?

**EDIT:**
These are the xdebug configuration lines from php.ini:

```
extension=ssh2.so
;extension=xdebug.so
zend_extension="/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so"
extension=mongo.so
extension=memcache.so
```

Comment: Have you checked your php error log file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that this line:

```
xdebug_start_trace('/home/dotancohen/xdebug');
```

Writes to this file:

```
/home/dotancohen/xdebug.xt
```

Therefore, `touch`ing `~/xdebug.xt` and `chmod`ing it to 777 resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

try to call xdebug_start_trace without parameters to see if it's your directories and/or file that your script don't like :P

without parameters it will create a file in the current directory as configured by the xdebug.trace_output_dir

Comment: Thanks, in fact xdebug writes to /tmp (the default directory) just fine. Any idea why it might not be writing to my user's home? I would assume permissions, but it looks like they are set properly.

Comment: when you are in your script directory, does the command "cd /home/dotancohen/xdebug" works ?

Comment: It complains `Not a directory` because it is a file! UNIX convention is to call things that end in a `/` a directory, and to call things that don't a file (yes, I know that in UNIX _everything_ is a file). Note that I just tried using `xdebug_start_trace('/tmp/xdebug-special');` and that _does_ write to the expected file, so it probably is a permissions problem.

Comment: I fixed it, John, see my answer below. You won't believe what the issue was!